# Safari URL search uses yahoo instead of DuckDuckGo

Tags: macos, safari, search

I have DuckDuckGo set as my preferred search engine in Safari in both Safari > Preferences and in the URL search bar. However, when I type a search in the URL search bar Safari always uses Yahoo.

How might I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I found the cause of this problem. It was a Safari extension called 1 click PDF. Disabling the extension solved the problem for me.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! I'm glad you've resolved this. Can I suggest you add the solution as an actual answer to your question? Most importantly, this will ensure it's there to help others if/when they also have the same problem. It also means you're likely to gain some reputation as people upvote your answer. Finally, in case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: @Monomeeth I added an answer by the OPs comment